# Checked and Unchecked can be stopped when hitting Enter Key on a ToggleButton?

Tags: wpf, togglebutton

With out handling the Key events, the Enter key can be handled without performing the Checked and Unchecked functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to implement this without handlers pressing. But you can set the *`ClickMode`* for the `ToggleButton` in [`Hover`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.clickmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `Hover:` Specifies that the `Click event` should be raised when the mouse hovers over a control.

Example:

```
<ToggleButton Content="Test" 
              ClickMode="Hover" />
```

Now, `Checked` and `Unchecked` events triggering when your Cursor moving on the ToggleButton.

Comment: No, I cant leads the `ToggleButton` to `Hover` Mode. Since i ave extended the ToggleButton, I can do this by overiding the OnToggle Method.. Thanks..